# Iterate/Loop Through XML Node List

Tags: xml, shell, xmllint

I need to load an XML file and loop through a list of nodes in it to execute a shell script for each one using the attributes for each node as parameters for the script. Any ideas? Any help will be much appreciated.

Example of XML FIle:

```
<Config>
    <FREQUENCY>EVERYTIME</FREQUENCY>
    <TIMEOUT>60</TIMEOUT>
<COMMAND>/opt/test1.sh</COMMAND>

<FREQUENCY>EVERYTIME</FREQUENCY>
    <TIMEOUT>30</TIMEOUT>
    <COMMAND>/opt/test2.sh</COMMAND>
</Config>
```

Comment: Can't you just make 2 lines of input in a normal text file and the process it with `while read line ; do eval $line ; done < $file` ? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution involves an edit to the xml file: contain the frequency/timeout/command tags inside another tag:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m /Config/x -v FREQUENCY -o : -v TIMEOUT -o : -v COMMAND -nl <<END
<Config>
  <x>
    <FREQUENCY>EVERYTIME</FREQUENCY>
    <TIMEOUT>60</TIMEOUT>
    <COMMAND>/opt/test1.sh</COMMAND>
  </x>

  <x>
    <FREQUENCY>EVERYTIME</FREQUENCY>
    <TIMEOUT>30</TIMEOUT>
    <COMMAND>/opt/test2.sh</COMMAND>
  </x>
</Config>
END
```

```
EVERYTIME:60:/opt/test1.sh
EVERYTIME:30:/opt/test2.sh
```

Otherwise, assuming your xml file is this simple (and I *loathe* using text processing tools on xml):

```
awk -F '[<>]' -v OFS=: '
    $2 == "FREQUENCY" {f=$3} 
    $2 == "TIMEOUT" {t=$3} 
    $2 == "COMMAND" {c=$3}
    f && t && c {print f,t,c; f=t=c=""}
' <<END 
<Config>
    <FREQUENCY>EVERYTIME</FREQUENCY>
    <TIMEOUT>60</TIMEOUT>
    <COMMAND>/opt/test1.sh</COMMAND>

    <FREQUENCY>EVERYTIME</FREQUENCY>
    <TIMEOUT>30</TIMEOUT>
    <COMMAND>/opt/test2.sh</COMMAND>
</Config>
END
```

```
EVERYTIME:60:/opt/test1.sh
EVERYTIME:30:/opt/test2.sh
```

In either case, you can pipe the output into:

```
... | while IFS=: read freq timeout cmd; do
    something with "$freq" "$timeout" "$cmd"
done
```